# Call resize Method in dojo

Tags: dojo

I was wondering why dojo isn't responding to changes on a element?
I made an easy example to show my problem!

```
<html >
<head>
    <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script> 
    <script src='../dojo/dojo.js'></script>
    <script>
        require([
            "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
            "dijit/layout/ContentPane"
        ]);
        require(["dojo/dom","dojo/on","dojo/domReady!"], function(dom, on){

            on(dom.byId("tester"),"resize", function() { console.log('window on resize') });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" style="width: 50%;" >
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" id="tester">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine when I use `on(window,"resize", function());` but I have no idea why the example above doesn't work.

Comment: The resize method of BorderContainer is a method of widget, not a method of domNode. You are using dom.byId("tester") which return a dom node, try use "dijit/registry" .byId to get a widget variable.

Comment: See my "using aspect instead of on" in answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (use aspect instead of on):

```
<html >
<head>
    <script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script> 
    <script src='../dojo/dojo.js'></script>
    <script>
        require([
            "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
            "dijit/layout/ContentPane"
        ], function(BC, CP){
        require(["dojo/aspect","dojo/domReady!"], function(aspect){

            var bc= new BC({}, "tester");

            bc.startup();

            aspect.after(bc, "resize", function() { console.log('window on resize') });


        });
        });    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tester" style="width: 50%;height:100%;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```